# Couchdb view: matching all keys only

Tags: couchdb

I am using ektrop to query a view as so:

```
query = new ViewQuery().designDocId("_design/accounts").viewName("by_account").key(search).startKey(0).endKey(99);
```

This will return documents which match with the key `search` or those between the start and end key. I'm trying to get documents in the view which match both the `search` and the start/end keys. How do i obtain this?

My view is formed like this:

```
"by_account": {
           "map": "function(doc) { 
                     emit(doc.loginString,doc); 
                     emit(doc.enrolmentPercentage, doc); }"
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid emitting the doc as the value in map/reduce. It will be part of the index so index will be bigger and slower. Emit no value instead and use the "include_docs" query parameter to get the document.
2. You can't use the key parameter as well as the startkey and endkey(it's conflicting)

For this type of query, you have mainly 3 solutions :

1. Use Mango Query and the $or operator(you want the key to match "search" or something between 0 and 99)
2. Make two query (one that look for the key "search" and the other one with the "startkey" and "endkey"
3. Build a special view to this single request. For example, if the login string is "search", emit -1. Otherwise, emit the enrolment percentage. Then, query wit the startkey(-1) and endkey(99). On the client side, handle the -1 values as if they were search.

**Note** : As for solution 3, it could be handle in another way but I have done the best I could with the information I had.

Comment: For 3, how do you choose to emit -1 when the search is "search"? As far as my understanding goes, there is no way to pass arguments to the `map` function, so i cant decide when to emit -1 or another value. Thanks

Comment: The emit function is called inside a javascript function. So you can do if(loginstring == "search") emit(-1,val)

Comment: `"search"` is input from the user. i cannot hard code it into the `if` as you did

Comment: Oh, I wasn't clear from your problem description. Perhaps, Mango is your solution. If you absolutly want to do it with map and reduce, you will have to do multiple queries or in-memory filtering.